# Class of parametric functions: bounded partial derivatives wrt to supremum of parameter

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the following space of functions

$$
f(x,\theta)  \in C^{k,l}(\mathbb{R}^d \times \Theta;\mathbb{R}); \Theta \subset \mathbb{R}^p 
$$
Namely, $f$ is continuously differentiable $k$ times in $x$ and $l$ times in $\theta$.

And now consider the following class of $f$

$$
 C^{k,l}_\uparrow(\mathbb{R}^d \times \Theta;\mathbb{R}) 
$$
where is the $f \in C^{k,l}(\mathbb{R}^d \times \Theta;\mathbb{R}) $ such that

$$
 \sup_{\theta \in \Theta} \lvert\partial_\theta^\alpha\partial_x^\beta f(x,\theta) \rvert
\leq C(1+|x|)^\lambda
$$
for some universal constants $C$ and $\lambda$ and $\alpha,\beta$ are multi-indices satisfying
$$
0\leq \sum_{i=1}^p \alpha_i \le l \text{ and } 0\leq \sum_{i=1}^d \beta_i \le k.
$$

I am trying to understand the importance of this class.

If we have a function with a bounded derivative then we get that function is Lipschitz.
Having Lipschitz implies having a linear growth condition.

Does this class of functions mean up to some order of partial derivatives in the two arguments $x$ and $\theta$ we have linear growth of $\sup_{\theta \in \Theta}f(x,\theta)$?

Or is there more this implies?

Additionally, is there a name for this class of functions?